How to get LUKS full disk enctryption passward dialog window back
Hi I run a Gnome Version 3.32.2 on Rocky 8.10 and on boot, I used to get a Gnome window / dialog box asking me for my full disk encryption password.
About 2 months ago, that changed to me seeing the CLI / terminal screen report that firewire would be deprecated, and I could enter the LUKS password on this terminal screen.
I assume that once the firewire warning would be over, Gnome DE would revert to me once again seeing a Gnome window / dialog box asking me for my full disk encryption password.
But that has not happened.
How do I get this window / dialog box back?

On which OS are you?

Hi I am on Rocky Linux 8.10 - It is a clone of Red Hat Enterprise 8.10

It seems that your plymouth theme has been modified (maybe by accident or by being deprecated or by some misconfigurations by a process), I suggest you to change your default plymouth using the following command:
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

and then to apply the changes run:
sudo update-initramfs -u

also, to install new community created themes you can visit Gnome-Look.

Thanks for your reply - I will learn about this and then try it

Have you tried it @ironfish?

Hi, thank you for the follow up. I have not tried it as yet, TBH because I am not an IT or Linux expert, I am a little afraid that I may make a mistake and screw things up. But I will try it in the future. Thank you again for taking the time to have helped me with your very thorough answer.
